# form_for and form_tag, when to use which one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading a Rails book and so far it has been using `form_for` to create the forms. In the new chapter that it is building a login page for users, it is using `form_tag` instead.
So I wanted to know when and how we should know which one to use? Is it just a educational thing he has done to also show this `form_tag` too ? or there are more technical reasons that should be considered?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) simply creates a form. [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for) creates a form for a model object. They are not interchangeable and you should use the one that is appropriate for a given case.

`form_for` is a bit easier to use for creating forms for a model object because it figures out what url to use and what http method to use depending on whether the object is a new record or a saved record.

Answer (score 16):

In most cases when you are sending data to your database with a model, in methods like `create`, `update`, `destroy`. For this type of action you can use `form_for`.

Instead `form_tag` only create a simply `form` html, for example, a search:

```
 <%= form_tag("/search", :method => "get") do %>
   <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
   <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
   <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I like this because your example hints at the fact that `form_tag` is often used for a "search" functionality, as it usually doesn't perfectly map to a Controller#action

Comment: I'd add that form_tag is good for creating session based forms. and as you say, when interacting with a database - form_for is the way to go.