# how can i use form_tag to replace form_for in form partial in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, edit, form-for

i want to use form_tag to replace the form for, in the following form_partial for new and edit forms.

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <% if @user.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this user from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

how can i change this form so that it will work for new and edit actions by using form_tag instead of form_for.

Comment: have a look  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463946/form-for-and-form-tag-when-to-use-which-one

Comment: but how to use this for edit form? in edit form will this show the fields with the values that are  already there in the database?(like the scaffold generated edit form)

Comment: check this http://railscasts.com/episodes/165-edit-multiple?view=asciicast, it has an example for form_tag