# Cannot pass through params using select_for on a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create users using a form, and inside the form I have some select_for tags.

The error I'm getting is the following:  param is missing or the value is empty: shifter

I don't understand why this is the case, as all parameters are appearing when I do a binding.pry print

```
[1] pry(#<ShiftersController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"1lilvIvZQeKawJDKHVhGzuerAOhQyxCz2kC6/MncWgiJz3lhFvOvt+N3XEc37kf7bhW1OIVG4IKdl26xvtXKKA==",
 "name"=>"Alex",
 "surname"=>"Swiec",
 "email"=>"alex@alexswiec.com",
 "password"=>"password",
 "batch_id"=>"1",
 "accesslevel_id"=>"2",
 "alumni"=>"false",
 "commit"=>"Create New Profile",
 "controller"=>"shifters",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

The controller I have is the following one

{

```
class ShiftersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :check_logged_in  # check_logged_in is in the applications controller 
    before_action :set_shifter, only: [:edit, :update, :show]
    before_action :require_same_user, only: [:edit, :update]

    def new
        @shifter = Shifter.new
    end 

    def create
        binding.pry 
        @shifter = Shifter.new(shifter_params)

        @intakeprofile = @shifter.intakeprofile
        if @shifter.save & @intakeprofile.save
            flash[:success] = "New Shifter created successfuly"
            redirect_to shift_projects_path
        else
            render 'new'
        end

    end 

    def edit 
        #before edit we call set_shifter to know which shifter to select
    end 

    def update
        #before update we call set_shifter to know which shifter to select
        if @shifter.update(shifter_params)
            flash[:success] = "Your profile has been update"
            redirect_to shifter_path(@shifter)
        else 
            render 'edit'
        end 
    end 

    def show
        #before show we call set_shifter to know which shifter to select
    end 


    def index 
        @shifters = Shifter.all.order("created_at DESC")
        @batches = Batch.all
    end 

    private 

        def shifter_params
            params.require(:shifter).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :password, :batch_id, :accesslevel_id, :alumni )
        end

        def set_shifter 
            @shifter = Shifter.find(params[:id])
        end 


        def require_same_user 
            if current_user != @shifter
                flash[:danger] = "You can only edit your own profile"
                redirect_to root_path
            end 
    end
end
```

}

And the view is the following one:

{

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @shifter %>

<div class="row">
    <div class="well col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <%= form_tag '/shifters/#{@shifter.id}/edit' do %>

        <%= label_tag :name %>
        <%= text_field_tag :name %>

        <%= label_tag :surname %>
        <%= text_field_tag :surname %>


        <%= label_tag :email %>
        <%= text_field_tag :email %>

        <%= label_tag :password %>
        <%= password_field_tag :password %>

        <%= label_tag :batch_id %>
        <%= select_tag :batch_id, options_for_select([['November 2013', 1], 
                                                      ['February 2014', 2], 
                                                      ['June 2014', 3],
                                                      ['October 2014', 4],
                                                      ['February 2015', 5],
                                                      ['June 2015', 6],
                                                      ['October 2015', 7],
                                                      ['February 2016', 8],                                                  
                                                      ['June 2016', 9],                                           
                                                      ['October 2016', 10],                                                   
                                                      ['February 2017', 11],
                                                      ['June 2017', 12]                                                   
                                                      ])  %>


        <%= label_tag :access_level_id %>
        <%= select_tag 'accesslevel_id', options_for_select([ ['Shifter', 2], ['Coach', 3], ['Admin', 1]])  %>


        <%= label_tag :alumni %>
        <%= select_tag 'alumni', options_for_select([['Yes', false], ['No', false]])  %>


<br><br>


        <%= submit_tag(@shifter.new_record? ? 'Create New Profile' : 'Update Profile', class: "btn btn-success") %>

        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> param is missing or the value is empty: shifter

The [**`require`**](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) in the `shifter_params` method expects a `shifter` key to be present in the `params` hash and since it is absent, you get that error.

**Solution:**

Change `shifter_params` to like below

```
def shifter_params
  params.permit(:name, :surname, :email, :password, :batch_id, :accesslevel_id, :alumni )
end
```

Moreover, `form_tag` is used to create a *non-model* form. You should use `form_for`. I suggest you to read about [*form_tag vs form_for*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463946/form-for-and-form-tag-when-to-use-which-one)

Comment: Thanks @Pavan, this worked! Starting with rails, so not sure why shifter key is absent.  In all previous forms I've added the value sent and it worked.  How could I change the code so that shifter would be present?

Comment: @swiecone Have a look at `form_for` and change the `form_tag` helper methods to `form_for` helper methods. It isn't that difficult :)

Comment: Ok, thanks so much @Pavan! virtual high five for you, and btw this is the first question EVEN posted, so thanks for making it be such a great experience :)